# How to programatically open the optionMenu of an Activity when its first appears?

Tags: android, android-activity, menu

I so far tried to put the line openOptionsMenu(); in onCreate(), onResume() and within a runnable sent to runOnUIThread() from onCreate() and no luck yet - i get an exception:

```
11-16 10:14:57.499: E/AndroidRuntime(939): Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
```

How do i ensure execution of  openOptionsMenu(); right when the activity is running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Add the below method to your Activity and call up `openOptionsMenu()` from it like I have showed here.

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    openOptionsMenu();
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
}
```